# Help proving a problem about an even (in the functional sense) marginal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ have density function $f$ and let $Y = X$ with probability $0.5$ and $Y = -X$ with probability $0.5$. Show that $Y$ is symmetric about $0$, that is $f_Y(y) = f_Y(-y)$.

What I don't understand is how this is even possible considering that $Y=X$ and $Y=-X$ are two lines in the $x,y$ plane, the area of the joint distribution function over this domain should be relatively small ?

Comment: "the area of the joint distribution function over this domain should be relatively small" No idea what this refers to. Please explain. What area? How related to the question?

Comment: By the way, it's actually the case that $f_Y$ is even, not odd. I fixed the title.

Comment: oh sorry I missed that, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $Y=XZ$ where $$\mathbb P(Z=1) = \mathbb P(Z=-1) = \frac12.$$
Then for any $y\in\mathbb R$,
\begin{align}
F_Y(y) &= \mathbb P(Y \leqslant y)\\
&= \mathbb P(XZ\leqslant y)\\
&= \mathbb P(XZ\leqslant y, Z=1) + \mathbb P(XZ\leqslant y, Z=-1)\\
&= \mathbb P(XZ\leqslant y\mid Z=1)\mathbb P(Z=1) + \mathbb P(XZ\leqslant y\mid Z=1)\mathbb P(Z=-1)\\
&= \frac12\left(\mathbb P(X\leqslant y) + \mathbb P(-X\leqslant y) \right)\\
&= \frac12\left(F_X(y) + 1 - F_X(-y) \right).\\
\end{align}
As the distribution function of $Y$ is differentiable, $Y$ is continuous, so we may compute the density by differentiation:
\begin{align}
f_Y(y) &= \frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dy} F_Y(y)\\
&= \frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dy}\left[\frac12\left(F_X(y) + 1 - F_X(-y) \right)\right]\\
&= \frac12\left(f_X(y) - f_X(-y)\right).
\end{align}
By symmetry it is evident that $f_Y(y) = f_Y(-y)$.

Comment: could you maybe explain why $P(XZ \le y, Z = 1) + P(XZ \le y, Z= -1) = P(XZ \le y)$ ? I would understand if I knew that $Z$ could only be either $1$ or $-1$, but is that really the case ?

Comment: Writing $Y=XZ$ where $Z$ is independent of $X$ and has Rademacher distribution is just a more convenient way of saying "$Y = X$ w.p. $\frac12$ and $Y=-X$ w.p. $\frac12$."

Comment: Okay, I totally understand this now. This is a fantastic solution, thanks so much!